# how to send the a zip file as response in node js?

Tags: node.js

HI all i had tried to send the response as bellow

```
exports.zipfile = function(req, res) {
var zip = new require('node-zip')()
zip.file('zipfile.file', 'hello there')
var data = zip.generate({
    type : 'string'
})

var archiver = require('archiver');
var fs = require('fs');
var StringStream = require('string-stream');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var dl = archiver('zip')
    dl.pipe(response)
    dl.append(new fs.createReadStream('/qtiexp/routes/zipfile.xml'), {
        name : 'YoDog/SubFolder/static.txt'
    })
    dl.append(new StringStream("Ooh dynamic stuff!"), {
        name : 'YoDog/dynamic.txt'
    })
    dl.finalize(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(200000)
    })
}).listen(13000);
```

};

but still i'm getting listen Eaddrinuse error 
i want to send a xml zipfile  as res from nodejs to front end

Comment: `EADDRINUSE` is caused when you have another process listening on the same port.

Comment: but i'm running servers on different servers one is 3000 and other is 13000

Comment: check other processes within each server then...

Comment: had checked but same error

Comment: See who else is listening on port 13000 using `netstat`.

Comment: okie i 'll check but before that code is correct no to send the zip file as response?

Comment: do `pkill node` and try run the server again __warning__ this will kill all your _node_ process

Answer (score 0):

Use netstat to find which process is using the port.

```
$ netstat -onp tcp
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    127.0.0.1:60472        127.0.0.1:62522        ESTABLISHED     408
TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        127.0.0.1:60472        ESTABLISHED     1204

$
```

You can even use grep to narrow it down:

```
$ netstat -onp tcp | grep 13000
TCP    127.0.0.1:13000        127.0.0.1:62522        ESTABLISHED     408

$
```